# J2ME FileConnection

Tags: java-me

How can i delete a directory (folder) that contains files or/and other folders in j2me?
I know how to use fileconnection but it can not delete a folder that contains other folders or files.

Answer (score 4):

well, if your device doesn't allow deletion of non-empty folders, presumably, delete every file in the folder first, then delete the empty folder...

Answer (score 3):

Here is the some code..

```
String url="file:///localhost/somedir";  //in some devices localhost will be root or user
FileConnection localdir=(FileConnection)Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE);
if(localdir.exists())
{
   Enumeration list=localdir.list();  //gives u total files list (files +dir)
   while(list.hasMoreElements())
   {
       String fileName=(String)list.nextElement();
       FileConnection localfile=(FileConnection)Connector.open(url+"/"+fileName,Connector.READ_WRITE);
          if(localfile.exists())
             localfile.delete();
    }
    //atlast delete the directory too
     localdir.delete();
}
```

delete all the files and directories and then delete the original directory.

hope this will help..